# MySQL - 1 large table with 100 columns OR split into 5 tables and JOIN

Tags: mysql, optimization, join

I had a 'large' MySQL table that originally contained ~100 columns and I ended up splitting it up into 5 individual tables and then joining them back up with CodeIgniter Active Record...

From a performance point of view is it better to keep the original table with 100 columns or keep it split up.

Each table has around 200 rows.

Answer (score 2):

200 rows?  That's nothing.

I would split the table if the new ones combined columns in a way that was meaningful for your problem.  I would do it with an eye towards [normalization](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html).

You sound like you're splitting them to meet some unstated criteria for "goodness" or because your current performance is unacceptable.  Do you have some data that suggests a performance problem that is caused by your schema?  If not, I'd recommend rethinking this approach.

No one can say what the impact on performance will be.  More JOINs may be slower when you query, but you don't say what your use cases are.

Answer (score 1):

So you've already made the change and now you're asking if we know which version of your schema goes faster?

(if the answer is the split tables, then you're doing something wrong).

Not only should the consolidated table be faster, it should also require less code and therefore less likely to have bugs.

You've not provided any information about the structure of your data.

And with 200 rows in your database, performance is the last thing you need to worry about.

Comment: Yes, I made the change and it was hard to find a definitive answer as some people say split at 30 columns with 1:1 relationship between tables, others say keep in 1 table cos faster... I know the JOINS should slow it down and 99% of the fields are full. 200 now but it's in test and will grow... I know 200 will go fast either way but from a best design POV what is the best way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Important thing is - you can (and its good style!) move columns containing temporary data into separate table. You can move optional columns into separate table (this depends on logic).

When you are making a database the most important thing is: each table should incapsulate some essence. You should better create more tables, but separate different essences into different tables. The only exclusion is when you have to optimize your software, because 'straight' logical solution works slowly.

If you deal with some very complicated model, you should divide it into few simple blocks with simple relations - this works with database design as well.

As for perfomance - of course one table should give better perfomance since you would not need any kind of joins and keys to access all data. Less relations - less lags.

Comment: It's not even for normalization, it's just to avoid a single table with 100 odd columns...           The performance does not seem to be lagging in any way as there's only ~200 rows...  

From a speed/optimization/best practice POV is it best to keep in the single table or split em all up?  

  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913911/how-many-columns-in-mysql-table

Comment: Thanks for the reply... in the table 99% of fields contain data (VARCHAR), and at ~200 rows it's small but I'm just wondering from a speed/best practice point of view: 1 table with 100 columns or 5 with 20 columns... think I'm just adding overhead with joins for the sake of keeping the amount of columns in a table low...

Comment: Speed is simply not an issue with 200 rows unless you're running this on an Atari 800. The entire table will fit into memory and any performance difference will be difficult to measure.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you're referring to is called vertical partitioning and it can have surprising effects on performance.  On a [Mysql.com Performance Post](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/performance-partitioning.html) they discuss this in particular.  An excerpt from the article:

> Although you have to do vertical
>   partitioning manually, you can benefit
>   from the practice in certain
>   circumstances. For example, let's say
>   you didn't normally need to reference
>   or use the VARCHAR column defined in
>   our previously shown partitioned
>   table.